# Access variable from router in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on a web application with Angular. I have created a header that is included in the index.html, so it is fixed to every page and the content of the page is injected through a ui-view. My question is: if I want to only show this header *after* the user has passed the signup and login pages, what should I do?

I have added a variable to my router as shown below, but I am not sure how to access the router's variable from the index.html, as it is not attached to a controller (since it is fixed content across all pages). I intended to simply throw an ng-hide="hideHeader" in the index.html.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        hideHeader: true
    })

    .state('signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/signup/signup.html',
        controller: 'signupController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        hideHeader: true
    })

    .state('landing', {
        url: '/landing',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/landing/landing.html',
        controller: 'landingController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        hideHeader: false
    })

    .state('account-management', {
        url: '/account-management',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/account-management/account-management.html',
        controller: 'accountManagementController',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
        hideHeader: false
    });
});
```

How can I access this hideHeader value from the index.html? Is there a way to set a global scope variable and get the value from there?

Comment: Just a note, ng-if is lighter weight than ng-hide/ng-show, so I would use it when possible. Also, when added data to a state, you should use the data parameter as can be seen in the documentation [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a different approach:  Create a service specifically for authentication (login/logout) and authentication status.  Then just call that service in your header.  Given that the header is dependent on your authentication, then it makes sense to abstract that away.  Your login/signup controllers will interact with this service.

Your routes can now also call this service to see if they should allow the user to view them based on login status.

Comment: I agree that this is the most reusable solution if there are many controllers that will rely on authentication having taken place. It will also allow for centralized access to user permissions, data, etc.